# The ssh connection is lost when force quit a window

Tags: server, ssh, 19.04, opencv, jupyter

I'm using `ssh` to connect to the server (Ubuntu 19.04) and work with `jupyter-notebook`. I open a window using `OpenCV`, and then when I want to close the window, I should force quit it, because the close button doesn't work. Doing this, the ssh connection is lost.
here is my code:

```py
from pypylon import pylon
import cv2

# conecting to the first available camera
camera = pylon.InstantCamera(pylon.TlFactory.GetInstance().CreateFirstDevice())

# Grabing Continusely (video) with minimal delay
camera.StartGrabbing(pylon.GrabStrategy_LatestImageOnly) 
converter = pylon.ImageFormatConverter()
# print(converter)
# exit()
# converting to opencv bgr format
converter.OutputPixelFormat = pylon.PixelType_BGR8packed
converter.OutputBitAlignment = pylon.OutputBitAlignment_MsbAligned

while camera.IsGrabbing():
    grabResult = camera.RetrieveResult(5000, pylon.TimeoutHandling_ThrowException)

    if grabResult.GrabSucceeded():
        # Access the image data
        image = converter.Convert(grabResult)
        img = image.GetArray()
        cv2.namedWindow('title', cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
        cv2.imshow('title', img)
        cv2.waitKey()
    grabResult.Release()

# Releasing the resource    
camera.StopGrabbing()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

What's the problem?